# set environment variable for java -cp command

Tags: java, environment-variables

Question : i want to set environment variable for java command.

below is my java command where in i'm setting/passing the environment variable in sh script (linux os)

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dvar1="val1" -Dvar2="var2" -Dvar3="val3" -cp "/local/apps/someusr/test/test.jar" com.test.TestBatchLauncher
```

but when do `System.getenv("var1")` in my java code, i'm getting null

so in summary how do i pass/set environment variable from `java -cp "/local/apps/someusr/test/test.jar" com.test.TestBatchLauncher`

so i even tried below export as well

```
export var1="val1"
export var2="val2"
export var3="val3"
```

Comment: Java system properties are not realized as environment variables. Use `System.getProperty()`.

Comment: @user207421 question edited, i want to set/pass env variables to java command and read the same in my java code

Comment: Well you aren't passing any environment variables in your comment line (apart from those that are exported by the command shell). `-D` sets system properties, not environment variables. So if you want to use `-D`, use `System.getProperty()`; if you don't want to use `System.getProperty()`, don't use `-D`.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using slash `/` instead of backslash `\`, I assume you are using Linux or macOS, which is using `bash` or `dash` or something similar (instead of Windows' `cmd.exe`).

Then you can pass "temporary" (that is, just useful for this command) environment variable like this:

```sh
var1=val1 var2=var2 var3=val3 $JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp "/local/apps/someusr/test/test.jar" com.test.TestBatchLauncher
```

Or set the environment variable like usual:

```sh
export var1=val1
export var2=var2
export var3=val3
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -cp "/local/apps/someusr/test/test.jar" com.test.TestBatchLauncher
```

---

Those `-D` can be get with `System.getProperty()`, not `System.getenv()`.

Comment: i've edited the question, tried with export command as well but still i'm getting null when i do System.getenv("var1")

Comment: @user2587669 Did you `export`ed then run `java` **in the same terminal**?

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up two different sets of key/value pairs. One such set are the operating system's (or rather the current shell's) collection of ***Environment Variables***.  These are made available to a Java program by being exported in the shell that runs the Java program.  The code accesses them by calling `System.getenv()`.  Here's an example:

Foo.java :

```
class Foo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(System.getenv("var1"));
       System.out.println(System.getenv("var2"));
       System.out.println(System.getenv("var3"));
   }
}
```

foo.sh:

```
#!/bin/sh

export var1="val1"
export var2="val2"
export var3="val3"

java Foo
```

Compiling the Java code and then executing the shell script results in this output:

```
val1
val2
val3
```

The other set of key/value pairs is Java's notion of ***System Properties***.  These can be set using the `-D` option on the `java` command line, and can then be referenced in the Java code with `System.getProperty()`.  Here's that one:

Bar.java

```
class Bar {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(System.getProperty("var1"));
       System.out.println(System.getProperty("var2"));
       System.out.println(System.getProperty("var3"));
   }
}
```

bar.sh

```
java -Dvar1=val1 -Dvar2=val2 -Dvar3=val3 Bar
```

Compiling Bar.java and running bar.sh produces the same output as the first example:

```
val1
val2
val3
```